# Non-error HTTP Unauthorized status

Tags: http-status-codes

Within our project we are using HTTP statuses to tell the client the state of their authentication. So when user is not logged in, the service will tell him 401. What is undesired is the fact that these will be logged in Google Chrome console looking like "There has been an error" whereas it is just "you are not logged in".

[image]

We also use other HTTP statuses like "Conflict", "Gone" and so – all of them raising errors in console. What would be the best practice in such case?

Comment: What is wrong with the console's appearance?  Also, are you sure your employer wants you posting the login page with an H&M ad to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Well some people complain saying we have erroneous scripts running. That is why.

Comment: You can always send a response code of `200` all the time, no?  Log errors on the server side as you normally would.